# Bloquear entrada de teclado y solo permitir entrada de lector de código de barras

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero restringir la entrada de datos a un textbox, que solo permita que los datos que entren sea a través de un escaner de código de barras y evitar que el usuario pueda teclear el código, ya que para teclear el código tiene que entrar como otro tipo de usuario.

Lo que intenté fue lo siguiente:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 1)
{

}
else
{
    textBox1.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("No puedes ingresar el codigo de manera manual");        
}
```

pero al parecer el código también afecta a lo que es el escaner.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de lograrlo.

Comment: El escaner aparece al computadora como un teclado.  Puede utilizar un "prefix" del escaner (el escaner puede añadir información antes del codigo) y si el texto no tiene ese prefix, muestra el mensaje de error.

Comment: si puedes utilzar el prefix puedes tomar la primera parte del texto como una validacion para que el textbox sepa que la entrada viene del scanner, lo unico que tendrias que hacer es esconder esos primeros caracters para que los usuarios no puedan replicarlo. para mayor efectividad trata de usar un carácter que no esté en el teclado.

Comment: como usaria el prefix es que no tengo ni la mas minima idea

Comment: No podrás simplemente deshabilitar el textbox, textbox.IsEnabled = fals, ésto para que no pueda el usuario ingresar texto manual, entonces guardar la cadena que te arroja el escaner en una variable string scan = LoQueArrojaElScanner , y esa cadena asignarla al textbox, textbox.text = scan.tostring();

Comment: el problema es como guardo la cadena del scaner sin el textbox y por ejemplo al usar el text changed solo toma la primera y luego ya despues toma la segunda, no entiendo como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

En si un lector de código de barras es un teclado mas, podrías prevenir interceptando su nombre con una librería HID para .NET si el dispositivo es USB.
Lo malo es que tendrías que aprender bien como usarlo.

Esta librería me ayudo, pero mas para almacenamiento en USB:

https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary

y su instalador en Package Manager Console:

**PM> Install-Package hidlibrary**

Comment: deja ver si puedo intentarlo pero pensaba que se podria con algo mas simple

Answer (score 0):

Aqui les dejo una opcion que desarrolle, sencilla, pero funcional.

Se coloca un timer y un contador que se iniciara con el evento "KeyUp" del textbox, el timer lo modifique a 10 milisegundos en lugar de los 100 que estan configurados por default.

Si el contador de caracteres alcanza un minimo rerquerido (7 en este ejemplo) el timer se detiene, en caso que alcance el contador de tiempo alcance los 50 milisegundos se limpia el textbox.

*-------------------------------*

```
public int contador;

    void TextBox1KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            contador = 0;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    
    void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contador ++;
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 7)  // Digitos minimos esperados
        {
            contador = 0;   
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            if (contador > 5) // Ajuste de tiempo entre caracteres 
            {
                textBox1.Text= "";          
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

*-------------------------------*